# PHP script running forever, ignoring max_execution_time

Tags: php, execution-time

The following script monitors the folder `/dev/shm/test` and outputs any created file in real time:

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
  0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
  1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
  2 => array("pipe", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('inotifywait -mc -e create /dev/shm/test/', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {

  header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8;");
  ob_end_flush(); //ends the automatic ob started by PHP
  while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
    print $s;
    flush();
  }
  fclose($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[0]);
  fclose($pipes[2]);

  // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
  // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
  $return_value = proc_close($process);

  echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
?>
```

The problem is that it never ends, runs forever. Any clue on why could this be happening? I have `max_execution_time = 30` in php.ini

How can I monitor how many resources this script uses?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess php is blocking and waiting for input from `fgets` and therefore can't check if max execution time is over.

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to read from STDOUT.  Was this the intent?  What happens if you define your own pipe to read from and give the child its descriptor for writing to?  If the maximum execution time is 30 but the script never ends, perhaps it never gets to execute due to being blocked on IO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max_execution_time defines the real time your script is allowed to run, so this does not includes any time spent outside of the script execution, even if it was triggered by it: database queries, filesystem polling, network, etc.

Solution is to use inotifywait's `-t <seconds>, --timeout <seconds>` option.

Comment: Just one doubt, will the script close in a future time after outputing many echoes?. The doubt is maybe silly, but the echo part is PHP execution time, or is it encapsulated inside the proc_open ?

Comment: echo is counted as PHP execution time. But I doubt you'll hit max_execution_time of 30s in your script, there would have to be many many changes in the directory.

Answer (score -1):

`max_execution_time` affects online execution only. CLI-based scripts run forever

Comment: The script outputs header, so it's not cli.

Comment: Just one doubt, will the script close in a future time after outputing many echoes?. The doubt is maybe silly, but the `echo` part is PHP execution time, or is it encapsulated inside the proc_open ?